# ASP.Net Core deployment to IIS server hierarchy for connectionstring info

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-core

I have successfully deployed an ASP.Net Core MVC app to an IIS server running on a windows VM using azure pipelines. The problem I have now is when I try to login I can't access the Sql Server database that has the info. I get the following error:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

SqlException: Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'.

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, object providerInfo, string newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, bool redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, bool applyTransientFaultHandling, string accessToken)
```

I don't understand why it is trying to use NT Authority. My connection string is of the following format: `Server=SQLSERVER;Database=DATABASE;user id=USERID;password=PASSWORD` Here are some things I have tried to get it to use the connection string:

1. Put the connection string in the appsettings.json of the project. This works when I run the project form VS Code but not for the iis server
2. Put the connection string in the webConfig
3. Add the connection string to the application pool in iis server manager
4. Add the connection string to the top level server in iis server manager

I do not want to use user impersonation. Not sure if this makes a difference but the way the people who coded the connection string was there is a section in the app.settings JSON which then has a connection string but there is no name for the connection string. Would putting a ConnectionString section in and naming it [like in this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/connection-strings) then doing any of the above work?

I have verified I can ping the sql server from the VM.

## Edit:

I am an idiot and had a hardcoded connection string so it depended on windows authentication which wasn't set up on the iis server VM

Comment: Have you tried passing in the connection string itself directly to your sql client?

Comment: @alans not sure exactly what you mean. How do I do that and what is the purpose? To ensure that the connection string is valid?

Comment: If you're using SqlClient, you would use SqlConnection and pass in the connection string as a parameter. If you're using EF Core, you pass in the connection string in UseSqlServer option during service configuration. Don't retrieve the connection string from webconfig, appsettings. Just pass in a literal connection string and see if that works first.

Comment: @alans I am an idiot. I had a hardcoded connection string that worked locally because windows authentication works locally. I changed that to get it from the appsettings.json and it works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You're welcome!